# Native Query with filter criteria

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, nativequery

We are trying to implement a search with filters. Our request body is 
    {
       "channelId":3 
    } and it is giving the records which have the channelId with 3. But when I try to pass an empty request body, {} to get all the records without any criteria, spring boot throwing error. we have a line in the code like this

```
Long channelId=  channelRequest.getChannelId() != null ? channelRequest.getChannelId():null;
```

and in the repository we have this.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value="select * " + 
        "from test_channel channelser0_ " + 
        + "where (:channelId is null or channelser0_.channel_id=:channelId)")
List<ChannelServiceMapping> getChannelIdAndServiceName(@Param("channelId") Long channelId);
```

error that we are getting is,

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bytea
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 310
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
coalesce(:channelId , null) is null
```

Query will be like

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value="select * " + 
        "from test_channel channelser0_ " + 
        + "where (coalesce(:channelId , null) is null or channelser0_.channel_id=:channelId)")
```

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bytea
 Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.